# New computers wont apply Computer Settings of Group Policy

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

Good morning everyone.  I have not been a sysadmin for long but since starting I have replaced close to 10 computers.  Everything usually works fine but i am noticing that they are not applying the Computer Settings portion of Group Policy from the DC.  What commands are used to apply the settings so that they will connect and I can stop getting Windows 10 prompts on my computers?

Comment: Have you tried `gpupdate /force`?

Comment: Yes I have.  I then rebooted it and checked with "gpresults /r" and it still doesnt show up.

Comment: Are they on the domain? Can they reach the DC?

Comment: I ran it from an elevated command prompt and it is showing up now but it still not updating the Group Policy when I reboot the computer after forcing the update.

Comment: Yes they are on the domain and can reach the Domain Controller just fine.  I put one of the PC's in the OU in Active Directory and it still doesnt update the Group Policy on the computer.

Comment: Are the computers directly in the OU where the GP is applied? Can you test with creating a new GP on the OU where the PCs reside? Does the gpresult output mention the last applied, filtered, .. GPs and the DC from where applied? What does it mean you have replaced the computers? Are the not-replaced ones in the same OU as the replaced ones?